# How to convert Hex String into Date

Tags: java

I have Hex "63 8a 60 f7" I need to convert it into Date. <Friday, December 2, 2022 20:33:02 UTC>

```
 long timeStamp = Long.parseLong("638a60f7", 16);
new Date(timeStamp);
```

but its giving wrong date "Tue Jan 20 13:23:33 IST 1970"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#%3Cinit%3E(long) cause this constructor return date after 1/1/1970 by those long value as seconds

Comment: `new Date(timeStamp*1000)` might work. But you would be even better of not using the deprecated `java.util.Date` class.

Comment: sorry ops i mean milliseconds

Comment: *but its giving wrong date "Tue Jan 20 13:23:33 IST 1970"* Because that's your time zone. You should be using `ZonedDateTime` though